# windows 2008R2 + Active Directory + printer x86 driver issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, drivers, print-server

i am setting a windows 2008 active directory server, and we have a NRG/Ricoh network printer. I configure it on the server with the x64 drivers (i add it up as a printer listed on the directory list, so in theory, the server will do the job of queueing), and it works fine when i print something from the 2008R2.

The issue comes when i try to add the x86 printer drivers on the server, so my windows xp SP3 workstation computers can add it from the directory list. But when i try, it says that are not compatible with the architecture. Its like i am trying to add x64 drivers, when they are supposed to be x32. I have researched all kind of official x32 NRG/Ricoh drivers, even with the universal ones, but it still gives me this error.

does anybody know whats the solution for this issue?

thank you very much in advance for your help and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the printer, click properties, and select the "Sharing" tab. There is an "additional drivers" button where you add the x86 drivers. You need to get to the .inf files for the driver for this to work. Most print drivers are self-extracting, but I use something like 7-zip to extract them and get at the .inf files easier.

Note that the x86 drivers must be an exact match of the x64 drivers in every way (version, name, etc) for this to work. You can't have v5.0 of the x64 driver and try to add v5.01 of the x86 driver this way.

Comment: ,hi.Thanks for your answer.I did what you refered to. Adding x86 drivers through "additional drivers" button. I also extract the drivers from the .zip, to obtain the .inf file asked when you try to add a new driver. what can i do if these are the drivers provided by Ricoh/NRG, and in theory, are the same version? these are the ones. I try to install the PCL6 ones for 2008R2(x64) and WindowsXP(x86): http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/re/model/mp33/mp33en.htm#Microsoft%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20%28x64%29

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're trying to ask me.

Comment: ,ok, dont worry.After researching on internet, i came across with some solutions. Here i post them just in case somebody come across with the same issue and is looking for solution in serverfault.Thank you very much by the way.http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverprint/thread/6067a35d-d9ac-4f52-8beb-9aca3f116e9e